# Should I repot this mint plant into a smaller pot?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, repotting, mint

This is a mint (field mint) plant grown from a cutting. I fell sick and couldn't water for two three days. Two of these dried and the last remaining one has dried edges and a light green appearance. Should I transplant this in a smaller pot for better rooting and oxygen supply? The pot is pretty big, almost 13~14 inches. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Usually I would recommend to always match plant size and pot size. However, you are dealing with a mint, so you can probably get away with just leaving it alone, for the following reasons:

First, mint grows and spreads quickly, so once it has recovered it will really take off.

Second, mint is fine even if the soil is overall a bit wetter, so one of the reasons smaller pots are recommended (quicker drying or absorption of water) is not that important here.

Now, of course you *can* transplant your cutting into a smaller pot, but you don’t necessarily have to.

However, looking at the leaves you seem to have a bit of a nutrition problem. It could be lack of fertilizer or issues with a specific mineral or ph. Maybe also an after effect of a dry pot. I can’t off the cuff diagnose what exactly is the issue, maybe that’s worth another question.

Comment: I have heard mint does not need fertilising, isn't it true?

Comment: @sam Mint usually doesn't need fertilizer, but the discolored leaves *might* be a sign of nutrient deficiency. Or they might be from the break in watering. I would give it some time to recover, and if it doesn't have new leaves with a healthy green color after a few weeks, consider adding some fertilizer.